# React router keeps redirecting back

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying solving this and read everything.

Below I have a successful request so I want to go to home page. It does go to home page but then redirects back. Here is a video https://monosnap.com/file/QOB2uIKXDrLpiVLsztxN9oAHSBuiY5. Any ideas? Thank you for your help.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

export default class New extends Component {
  createRequest(params) {
    if (Object.values(this.state.validations).includes(false)) { return }
    this.deliveriesService.create(params)
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.ok) {
        this.props.history.push("/");
      }
    })
  }
}
```

My Home Page looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import deliveriesService from "./services/deliveriesService.js";
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class Home extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      deliveries: []
    };
  }

  deliveries() {
    this.deliveriesService.index()
    .then((res) => {
      this.setState({
        deliveries: res,
      });
    })
  }

  render() {
    const deliveries = this.state.deliveries;
    return (
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my routes

```
import React from 'react'
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from "./Home";
import New from "./New";

const Main = () => (
  <main>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
      <Route exact path='/new' component={New}/>
    </Switch>
  </main>
)

export default Main
```

Comment: Can you show your Routes

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I just added them.